# is there a way in c++ to have derived classes override a base class static method?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a base class B that is derived many times: D1, D2, etc.

In class B i would like to have a static method getInfo() that returns a BaseInfo class (basically a class containing default member values for class B) so it would make sense to make it static, since there's no need for a specific instance.

Now, is there a way to force derived classes to implement this method?
obviously each derived class has it's own default values for class members.

Ideally it would be great if in base class i could declare the getInfo() as virtual static but since there's no such thing in C++ i was wondering if there's a nice way to implement this behaviour.

I was thinking about CRTP but didn't come up with a solution.

Comment: No, the only thing you can override is a virtual function and static functions cannot be virtual.

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the traits pattern.

```
template<typename T> struct base_traits;
```

Every class that you expect to `getInfo` from must specialize this type.

```
template<>
struct base_traits<B>
{
    static BaseInfo getInfo() { return b_info; }
};

template<>
struct base_traits<D1>
{
    static BaseInfo getInfo() { return d1_info; }
};

template<>
struct base_traits<D2>
{
    static BaseInfo getInfo() { return d2_info; }
};
```

To get the `BaseInfo` for any particular class, you write

```
BaseInfo d1info = base_traits<D1>::getInfo();
```

If somebody forgets to specialize `base_traits<T>` for their derived type `T`, you get a compiler error.

```
BaseInfo d3info = base_traits<D3>::getInfo();

error: incomplete type ‘base_traits<D3>’ used in nested name specifier
```

Answer (score 0):

> It would make sense to make it static, since there's no need for a specific instance.

There is in fact a need in a specific instance. Specifically, there is a need in the run-time type information stored in the instance. The only possible choice is to make the function virtual, and override it in derived classes.

Comment: But i do not need the specific implementation of a derived class instance... since i only need the member default values...

Comment: You do need to know that you have a derived class object. This information exists and can be found **only** in the object itself. Thus you do need an object. How general or specific this object is is irrelevant, you need one.